# Prevent Execution of ServletContainerInitializer or how to use absolute-order

Tags: java, glassfish, startup, servlet-3.0

is it possible to prevent the execution of the ServletContainerInitializer of a provided jar.

I want to prevent the execution of `JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java` which is provided by Glassfish 4.1 as an osgi-bundle (in `jersey-container-servlet.jar`).

Or how can I use the `<absolute-order>` of web.xml to enforce loading of the `ResteasyServletInitializer.java` provided in `resteasy-servlet-initializer-3.0.11.Final.jar` prior to the execution of the jersey counterpart?

I do not understand how this can be achieved using the web.xml.
Also the specification of `ServletContainerInitializer` states:

> In either case, ServletContainerInitializer services from web fragment JAR files excluded from an absolute ordering must be ignored, and the order in which these services are discovered must follow the application's classloading delegation model.

I therefore tried  in my glassfish-web.xml but with no effect.

Please guide me on this one.

Cheers

(p.s. removing  `jersey-container-servlet.jar` from the glassfish/modules/ folder "works")

Answer (score 0):

Web fragment ordering won't work, because the jersey-container-servlet.jar is not a real web fragment.

But the following works in Webogic 12.2, which uses Jersey 2.

Create class for your app

```
package my.app;

public class MyJaxRSApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {}
```

Register Rest Easy servlet with the fully qualified name of this class in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my.app.MyJaxRSApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

This will not prevent execution of JerseyServletContainerInitializer, but it won't register the Jersey servlet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll have a look into this as soon as I got time. Our current "work-around", deleting the jersey-container-servlet.jar is really not a longterm solution.